# Drop-down-picker item not clickable while open in react-native

Tags: react-native

enter code here I am building the app in react native and I am facing an issue with the drop-down-picker item selection. When we open the drop-down-picker the item shows but when we try to select any item then not able to select it. If we set the height to the view of the drop-down then it works fine. And if we remove the height and set "zIndex" for the view then it again not working. Please help to find any solution.

Thanks in Advance.

```
<View style={styles.root}>
      <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/background.png')} style={styles.image1}>
      
        <View style={{ position: "relative",  zIndex: 1 }}>

          {shouldShow ? (
            <View style={styles.fullWidthView}>

              <View style={styles.halfWidthView}>
                <Text style={styles.blackText}>Date From</Text>
                <View style={styles.inputStyle}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={showDatepicker}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>{selectedDate2}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  {show && (
                    <DateTimePicker
                      testID='dateTimePicker'
                      timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={0}
                      value={date}
                      mode={mode}
                      is24Hour={true}
                      display='default'
                      onChange={onChange}
                    />
                  )}
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.halfWidthView}>
                <Text style={styles.blackText}>Date To</Text>
                <View style={styles.inputStyle}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={showDatepicker}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>{selectedDate}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  {show && (
                    <DateTimePicker
                      testID='dateTimePicker'
                      timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={0}
                      value={date}
                      mode={mode}
                      is24Hour={true}
                      display='default'
                      onChange={onChange}
                    />
                  )}
                </View>
              </View>

            </View>
          ) : null}
        </View>

        <View style={{height: 100, position: "relative", zIndex: 10000 }}>

          {shouldShow ? (
            <View style={styles.fullWidthView}>

              <View style={styles.halfWidthView}>
                <Text style={styles.blackText}>Leave Status</Text>
                <View style={{
                  width: 150,
                  fontSize: 15,
                  position: 'relative',
                  zIndex:90000
                }}>
                  <DropDownPicker
                    items={leaveStatusItems}
                    placeholder='Select status'
                    labelStyle={{ color: '#000', fontSize: 15 }}
                    placeholderStyle={{ color: '#000' }}
                    containerStyle={{
                      height: 40,
                      flexDirection: 'column'
                      ,zInde:450000 

                    }}
                    style={{ color: '#000', fontSize: 15, position:'relative'}}
                    itemStyle={{
                      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                      height: 35, fontSize: 15
                    }}
                    dropDownStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa' }}
                    onChangeItem={item => setStatus(item.value)}
                    defaultValue={status}

                  />
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.halfWidthView}>
                <Text style={styles.blackText}>Leave Type</Text>
                <View style={{
                  width: 150,
                  fontSize: 15
                }}>
                  <DropDownPicker
                    items={leaveTypeItems}
                    placeholder='Select Type'
                    labelStyle={{ color: '#000', fontSize: 15 }}
                    placeholderStyle={{ color: '#000' }}
                    containerStyle={{
                      height: 40,
                      flexDirection: 'column',

                    }}
                    style={{ color: '#000', fontSize: 15, position:'relative',zInde:250000 }}
                    itemStyle={{
                      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                      height: 35, fontSize: 15
                    }}
                    dropDownStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa' }}
                    onChangeItem={item => setType(item.value)}
                    defaultValue={type}

                  />
                </View>
              </View>

            </View>
          ) : null}
        </View>

        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', position: 'relative', zIndex: 3 }}>

          <Text style={styles.orangeBoldText}>Recent Leaves:-</Text>

          <FlatList style={styles.flatList}
            data={leaveList}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={itemData => (
              <View style={styles.view3}>

                <Text style={styles.orangeBoldText}>{itemData.item.username}</Text>

                <View style={styles.horizontalView}>
                  <Text style={styles.grayText}>Subject :</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.grayText}>{itemData.item.title.toString().replace(itemData.item.username, "").replace(":", "").replace(" ", "")}</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.horizontalView}>
                  <Text style={styles.grayText}>Date :</Text>
                  <View style={styles.innerHorizontalView2}>
                    <Text style={styles.grayText}>{itemData.item.startDate.toString().split(" ")[0]}</Text>
                  </View>

                </View>

                <View style={styles.horizontalView}>
                  <Text style={styles.grayText}>Leave Type :</Text>
                  <View style={styles.innerHorizontalView2}>
                    <Text style={styles.grayText}>{itemData.item.leaveTypeName}</Text>
                  </View>

                  <View style={styles.innerHorizontalView}>
                    <View style={styles.greenBackground}>
                      <Text style={styles.whiteText}>{itemData.item.leaveStatusName}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>

                </View>
              </View>
            )}></FlatList>

        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put `flex=1` maybe its not taking the whole space
or try to post
thanks hope i helped you

Comment: try to post that piece a copy of the code

Comment: okey if the problem is in the androide app than try "elevation:1,", instead of zindex that works only for ios.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap the items with a touchable opacity and an onPress event and make sure you are passing the props and for the code make sure to put "zIndex" and not "zInde" in the drop down picker

```
  <DropDownPicker
                items={leaveTypeItems}
                placeholder='Select Type'
                labelStyle={{ color: '#000', fontSize: 15 }}
                placeholderStyle={{ color: '#000' }}
                containerStyle={{
                  height: 40,
                  flexDirection: 'column',

                }}
                style={{ color: '#000', fontSize: 15, 
                                              position:'relative',zIndex:250000 }}
                itemStyle={{
                  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                  height: 35, fontSize: 15
                }}
                dropDownStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa' }}
                onChangeItem={item => setType(item.value)}
                defaultValue={type}

              />
```